# Replaced OS X Mavericks During Ubuntu Installation - Can't Reinstall Mavericks

Tags: macos, ubuntu, hard-drive, mac

I installed Ubuntu on my 13-inch retina macbook pro (late 2013) and decided to erase OS X and replace with Ubuntu. I regret doing this since now my wifi isn't working (pretty sure it's a driver issue), and it's really slow to boot and there are some other quirks as well.

My question is how can I wipe Ubuntu and reinstall OS X. I rebooted my machine and held Command-R to reinstall Mavericks, but when it came time to choose a disk, there were none to choose from. I guess this makes sense since I assigned the entire hard disk to Ubuntu, but I would really like to reverse this.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated, and if you have any idea what I could do about the wifi that would be helpful as well, since I really do want to switch to Ubuntu I've just been experiencing so many weird hiccups and bugs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Mac is new enough that it should be able to [install the OS from the Internet](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), with no recovery partition needed on the hard disk. So you should be able to proceed with the recovery without choosing a disk to boot from.

Comment: I don't think it makes me choose a disk to boot "from", but a disk to download OSX "onto".

Comment: OK, you may need to use Disk Utility to wipe the existing partition on the disk and create a new one, if you can get that far in the process.

Comment: Ya that's probably right but I'm not sure how to partition the hard disk properly on Ubuntu.

Comment: I wouldn't try to use Ubuntu to do it, I'd run the OS X Disk Utility from the installation screen and use that to remove all partitions and then create a new one.